# Compare only date without time using Android Room

Tags: android, date, kotlin, android-room

I'm saving a Date object to the database using a TypeConverter for Room. It works just fine. However, I want to make a query where I compare only the "date" part of the Date object with only the "date" part of the timestamp. I want the time to be ignored. I tried using the `date()` function available on SQLite but I guess I'm using it wrong.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM event WHERE date(event_date) = date(:date)")
fun loadEventsByDate(date: Date): Flow<List<Event>>
```

```
class DateConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromTimestamp(value: Long?): Date? {
        return value?.let { Date(it) }
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun dateToTimestamp(date: Date?): Long? {
        return date?.time
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Issue/Explanation**

Your issue is that you are converting to/from (and thus storing) a unix date time in milliseconds but the SQLite `date` function *(and all SQLite date/time functions)* expects the date/time to match one of it's recognised formats.

- see [SQLite Date and Time Functions - Time Values](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html#time_values)

This is an example (using a hijacked project and thus User table) of how the data is stored using your type converter (date column):-

[image]

i.e. **13 digits**

As such the `date` function returns NULL (for both sides of the WHERE clause) and in SQLite NULL does not equal NULL hence you get nothing (if NULL were to equal NULL you would get all rows rather than a selection).

With the above data consider the following explanatory Query (with fix to the WHERE clause) :-

```
@Query("SELECT *, :date AS passed_date, coalesce(date(date),'ouch') AS cnv_date, coalesce(date(:date),'ouch') AS cnv_passed_date FROM user WHERE date(date / 1000,'unixepoch') = date(:date / 1000,'unixepoch');")
```

The result (using the example data above) will be (after writing it to the log) :-

```
2021-08-04 08:02:42.324 D/MYINFO: User = Susan date is Wed Aug 04 08:02:42 GMT+10:00 2021 passed date is 1628028162323 converted date is ouch converted passed date is ouch
2021-08-04 08:02:42.325 D/MYINFO: User = Fred date is Wed Aug 04 08:02:42 GMT+10:00 2021 passed date is 1628028162323 converted date is ouch converted passed date is ouch
2021-08-04 08:02:42.325 D/MYINFO: User = Mary date is Wed Aug 04 08:02:42 GMT+10:00 2021 passed date is 1628028162323 converted date is ouch converted passed date is ouch
```

- i.e. Room has handled extracting the date with no problems. However:-
- the date that has been passed via the parameter passed is 13 digits, so not a date. Therefore:-
- the date functions have both returned NULL (converted to **ouch** by the coalesce function) as the value passed is 1 13 digit unrecognosed date/time value.

**The/A Fix**

The where clause above includes a fix, that ensures that the date function is passed a suitable value for both. That is the 13 digit number is divided by 1000 to remove milliseconds and the unixepoch modifier is then applied.

As such you could try/use:-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM event WHERE date(event_date / 1000,'unixepoch') = date(:date / 1000,'unixepoch')")
fun loadEventsByDate(date: Date): Flow<List<Event>>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed explanation. It works fine. It's not mandatory for me to save the date using a timestamp. I did it because that's what is recommended on the docs: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data Is there a better way to save it if I want to be able to filter by date?

Comment: @unadivadantan, saving as a timestamp (Long) has the advantage of being more efficient; *if you don't need to use millisecs, then even less space if you divide by 1000 to drop the millisecs*. Storing as a String (just the date time) would be a minimum of 10 bytes as opposed to a maximum of 8 bytes for a Long. In short, there was no intention for "the issue" being a criticism.

Comment: Oh sure! Don't worry. I was just wondering if there was a better way to store the value for this use case. Thanks a lot ;)